# A film about a man in the future looking for a crystal cylindrical element to repair a machine

Tags: story-identification

It is a vague memory from the childhood. I remember well that it was a devastated post-apocalyptic world (or another planet) and the main character had to deal with human-like wild creatures in a dry desert-like environment.

I think the film might be from the 80s, or late 70s but I am not sure about the language; it could be a dubbed version and — me as a child — not noticing any difference.

Comment: Hi Vera.  Anything else you can add?  The approximate year that you saw this?  How old you think the film might be?  What was the primary language of the film?  The more details you can provide, the better.

Comment: Hi! I think the film might be from the 80s, or late 70s  but I am not sure about the language, it could be a dubbed version and me as a child not noticing any difference.

Comment: please update the question with that information.

Answer (score 3):

The cylindrical crystal is reminiscent of "[Demon with the Glass Hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_with_a_Glass_Hand)", an old *Outer Limits* episode, and the desert struggle with
human-like creatures sounds like [*Tank Girl*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114614/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).